# Asp.net Transaction with foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to save one Gridview with two checkbox in database with Asp.net Transaction , I am Getting Error when same condition come

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedure", con);
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("procedure1", con);
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvrecept.Rows)
{
    if (cash.Checked){
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", "value");
        cmd.Transaction = trns;
    }
    else if (cheque.Checked)
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", "value1");
        cmd1.Transaction = trns;
    }
}
int i = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (i > 0 && j > 0 )
{
    trns.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Please explain what error do you get. Also notice that inside the _else if_ block you add a parameter to the first cmd not to the second one. Is it a typo?

Comment: Also: the transaction should be added outside the loop, the parameters should be cleared at each loop, the execution of the command should be executed inside the loop. Finally if you execute a stored procedure you should set the CommandType property to StoredProcedure.

Comment: Yes The problem is when for each loop executing parameters are getting cleared ,I wants to save all together.. any method is there.. I don't have that much experiences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in my comment above you need to change something:
The trns should be added outside the loop just one time together with the setting to CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure and the creation of the two commands.

Inside the loop you should execute the command at each loop for each row you traverse. Also it is not clear if the two commands are mutually exclusive. I mean, if you have two checkboxes set then you should execute both commands but not if you don't have the matching checkbox set. If this is the case you need to use two separate ifs not an else if.
Notice that inside the loop you can simply change the value of the parameter before executing the command. This will be a smaller optimization but nevertheless it is simpler than creating the command or clearing the parameter collection at each loop.

Finally the commit of the Transaction should be done outside the loop when you have completed the insertion. If you have an error then an exception occurs and the Commit is skipped.

Final note. It is not clear why you need two commands at all. In the code above you use always the same StoredProcedure but passing different values. If this is the case then one command will do just fine.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedure1", con);
cmd.Transaction = trns;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("procedure1", con);
cmd1.Transaction = trns;
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@parameter1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvrecept.Rows)
{
    if (cash.Checked)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@parameter"].Value = "value";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    if (cheque.Checked)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@parameter1"].Value = "value1";
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
trns.Commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually my problem was when second time loop executing parameters doubling ,, anyway  issue solved using 'cmd.parameter.clear()'